# Which lifestyle to use for Console Application?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have an unit of work class which is registered with Simple Injector in a common assembly that is shared by various web apps.

It is registered as:

```
Container.Register(typeof(IUnitOfWork), typeof(UnitOfWork), new WebRequestLifestyle());
```

I now have a console application that needs to use the container defined in the assembly, but obviously cannot use `WebRequestLifestyle`. I get the following error if I try:

> The `IUnitOfWork` is registered as 'Web Request' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of a Web Request.

Is there an alternative I can use to `WebRequestLifestyle` that will achieve the same functionality but for both web and console applications?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there an alternative I can use to WebRequestLifestyle that will achieve the same functionality but for both web and console applications?

Yes there is. In Simple Injector v3 the advised pattern is to always use `Lifestyle.Scoped`:

```
Container.Register(typeof(IUnitOfWork), typeof(UnitOfWork), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

`Lifestyle.Scoped` is a 'placeholder lifestyle' that maps to the scoped lifestyle configured through `Container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle`.

This means that in your web application you will have to create a new `Container` instance using:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
```

This makes the rest of your configuration oblivious to the given end application.

In your console application, you should typically use the `AsyncScopedLifestyle`. This means the creation of your container will look as follows in your console application:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();
```

The `AsyncScopedLifestyle` can be used for both single threaded and asynchronous operations. It requires explicit management. This means you will have to manually start and dispose a scope before and after an operation. If your console application is short-lived, this will typically mean you do this in the main method:

```
void Main() 
{
    var container = BuildContainer();

    using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))
    {
        var service = container.GetInstance<MyRootType>();

        service.DoSomething();
    }

    container.Dispose();
}
```

In case the console application is long(er) running, it will probably handle multiple autonomous requests (much like individual web requests). In that case you will have to wrap each individual request with a scope (much like the example above).

For more information, [see the documentation](https://simpleinjector.org/console).

---

Edit: In case you're still using v3 in a console application, you'll need to use `LifetimeScopeLifestyle` from [`SimpleInjector.Extensions.LifetimeScoping`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Extensions.LifetimeScoping).

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new LifetimeScopeLifestyle();
```

To use it, replace the `using` from the example:

```
using (container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Steven; very informative answer as always.

Comment: @Steven, I'm seeing `/Workspaces/appature/git/ImsHealth.Patterns/src/ImsHealth.Patterns.SimpleInjector/ConsoleApplicationContext.cs(18,60): warning CS0618: 'LifetimeScopeLifestyle' is obsolete: 'This lifestyle is obsolete. Please use SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.ThreadScopedLifestyle instead.'` Any comments on that?

Comment: Especially confusing when i see this on the SimpleInjector documentation under the PerThread lifestyle: `This lifestyle is deliberately left out of Simple Injector because it is considered to be harmful. Instead of using Per Thread lifestyle, you will usually be better of using one of the Scoped lifestyles.`

Comment: @AndyCunningham: a per-thread lifestyle is someting different than a lifetime scope. With a scoped lifestyle, instances get a very deterministic lifetime, while per-thread instance lifetime is very undeterministic.

Comment: @Steven, I just upgraded the SimpleInjector and now it says BeingLifetimeScope() is obsolete. If I'm using a Hybrid lifestyle how can I start a scope with the newer version?

Comment: @SimpleFellow: The obsolete method should point you at which method you need to use. If in doubt, please post a question with the appropriate details [here](https://github.com/simpleinjector/simpleinjector/issues/new).